# how to use cURL in facebook graph api request

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, file-get-contents

I am getting the information to facebook graph api using file_get_contents()

but sometimes I am receiving an error.

I found out that cURL must be used instead of file_get_contents().

The problem is, I don't know how to use cURL with the URL that I need to pass.

if I converted

```
file_get_contents($graph_url);
```

into cURL, what will be the code?

here is the content of $graph_url

```
$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
  . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
  . "&message=" . urlencode('')
  . "&method=POST"
  . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
```

Comment: Read the cURL documentation on how to make requests.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";
  $postData = "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
  . "&message=" . urlencode('')
  . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
                
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: how about if my $graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. 'fql?q=SELECT+src_big+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id='.$photo_id. '&access_token=' . $access_token;

Comment: for fql, `file_get_contents` is more suitable. I used this function with fql.

Comment: if you want to use `curl` anyhow, just change `CURLOPT_POST` to `0` and remove `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option. also your complete url will be `$graph_url = 'graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+src_big+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id='.$photo_id. '&access_token=' . $access_token;`

Comment: @EM-Creations, your edit is not correct, $graph_url is used for CURLOPT_URL option. $photo_url was used in POST parameter, please undo the change

Comment: @MaulikVora I understand now after re-reading thanks.

Comment: would be much prettier using http_build_query() ^^