# How to use Guzzle on Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, http, post, get, guzzle

I am creating a web application on Codeigniter 3.2 which works with the Facebook Graph API. In order to make GET & POST HTTP requests, I need a curl library for Codeigniter. I have found Guzzle but I Don't know how to use Guzzle on Codeigniter.

Comment: My opinion is that cURL isn't that hard to use and that Guzzle (while very slick) is major overkill for your needs. Spend some time looking at the [PHP cURL manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and then check SO for examples - [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203310/how-to-use-curl-in-facebook-graph-api-request)

Answer (score 7):

Check this link:

https://github.com/rohitbh09/codeigniter-guzzle

```
  $this->load->library('guzzle');

  # guzzle client define
  $client     = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

  #This url define speific Target for guzzle
  $url        = 'http://www.google.com';

  #guzzle
  try {
    # guzzle post request example with form parameter
    $response = $client->request( 'POST', 
                                   $url, 
                                  [ 'form_params' 
                                        => [ 'processId' => '2' ] 
                                  ]
                                );
    #guzzle repose for future use
    echo $response->getStatusCode(); // 200
    echo $response->getReasonPhrase(); // OK
    echo $response->getProtocolVersion(); // 1.1
    echo $response->getBody();
  } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    #guzzle repose for future use
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    print_r($responseBodyAsString);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate Guzzle into Codeigniter 3.x by following the following steps:

**NOTE**: *I was doing this on **Windows**, should work on other platforms too.*

1. Open the command terminal on your computer
2. Change directory to your Codeigniter app installation (i.e. my app is called **MyCodeigniterApp**)

> `cd C:\wamp64\www\MyCodeigniterApp`

3. Install Composer in that directory by running the following command on the terminal

> `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

4. After installing Composer, we can now install Guzzle by running the following command on the terminal

> `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

if you encounter the following error while executing the above command
[image: [RuntimeException] require-dev.mikey179/vfsStream is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use mikey179/vfsstrea m instead.]

follow the recommendation in the error message.

Open `composer.json` located in your App root folder i.e. `C:\wamp64\www\MyCodeigniterApp`

then change

> "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"

to

> "mikey179/vfsstream": "1.1.*"

You can now re-run the command in step 4 to install Guzzle

5. After successful installation of Guzzle, you now need to make the following changes to the `config.php` file under the `application/config` directory

make the following changes under `Composer auto-loading` section and let the configuration be:

> $config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';

6. The integration is complete, now you can use Guzzle in your controllers or models as below or by following the guides from Guzzle documentation on https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

   ```
    //Create guzzle http client
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
        'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
    ]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // "200"
    echo $res->getHeader('content-type')[0];
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'
   ```

DONE.......